# How should I populate nested elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to display NEWS headines on my website. I want to populate it using Jquery. I have written the code but nothing is displayed on webpage.

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                        <strong>Latest Headines</strong>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">
                            <h2> </h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">
                            <h2> </h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">
                            <h2> </h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">
                            <h2> </h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">
                            <h2> </h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json.articles.length);

        function headlines (json) {
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
                $('.sidebar-nav li a h2').eq(i).html(json.articles[i].title);
            }
        }
});
});
```

I have made a class called sidebar then inside class I have placed list and anchor followed by `<h2></h2>` tag. I want to populate `h2` tag with NEWS headlines but nothing is displayed on my webpage.

[image]

Comment: Do you see the console logs in callback? If so what does data look like? If not add error handler

Comment: Note you never call `headlines()`

Comment: You are only creating the functions headline, you need to call your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.sidebar-nav li').eq(i).find('h2').html(...)`

`li` is the Nth element you're looking for, not `h2`.

For that matter, you should cache the nav element or the `li`s, to avoid hammering the DOM :

```
var $lis = $('.sidebar-nav li')

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
     $lis[i].find('h2').html(json.articles[i].title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You don't call your function headlines so nothing goes to output ;)

Second one:

```
$('.sidebar-nav li a h2').eq(i)
```

will only work for the first item i think, because there is only 1 H2-Tag within the a-Tag.
I suggest giving all H"-Tag a class like ".headline" and itterating over them.

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: should I remove `<h2>` tag and just populate `<a>`. Is it good practice to populate `<h2>` inside `<a>` or just populate `<a>`

Comment: I think both ways are okay to go so choose the simplest. In this case removing h2 and styling directly the a-tag is straight forward.